# S'fat Emet Likkutim

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, jewish-books

Is the *S'fat Emet Likkutim* available online? It's [listed](https://www.responsa.co.il/Books/Books.en-US.html) as being available on Bar Ilan but I can't actually seem to find it there.

NB I definitely mean *S'fat Emet Likkutim* and not just the regular *S'fat Emet*.

Comment: The Likkutim listed on Bar Ilan are on Shas: https://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%AA.html?id=0tAqzQEACAAJ

Comment: Aha - it's the Torah ones I'm after

Comment: Seems like you'll have to go the old fashioned route - Otzar Hachochma